# Finding Open Port TCP Communication

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, serversocket

I'm writing a Java application like AIM where I want a lookup server to help two clients connect to each other with the ServerSocket class. Unfortunately a serversocket needs an open port or it will be blocked by your firewall. Without having the clients manually change their firewall settings is there a way I can either find an open port, open a port (it's okay if it asks for permission) I just don't want every client to manually have to change firewall settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a ServerSocket is what opens the port on the server end (assuming the port is NOT also blocked on the firewall). On many systems, port numbers <1024 are not blocked by the firewall, and therefore often don't require custom configuration. However, since many ISPs have been more and more stringent with what ports they block within their network, many pieces of software have moved to operating over port 80. Why port 80? It's the port used for HTTP, and therefore pretty much open (at firewalls) 100% of the time for any service that operates on the web.

To answer the question of how to find an open port, port scanners perform this function. Basically all they do is try to establish a connection on a range of ports (say port 1-1024). When a connection is successful (in Java you would see this as a good connection over a Socket), you can consider that port "open". You don't need to exchange any data in order to make the connection, you just need to establish the connection, and then close it.

Also, if there is no server software of any kind running on the server, it won't appear "open", even if it isn't blocked. Without a successful Socket (TCP) connection, you won't know what ports are not blocked by user's firewall.

To reiterate, I'm switching back and forth between two related, but separate concepts. Firewalls can block/open ports, or have port forwarding. That's not the same as a port being "open" for connections on a given machine. In order for a machine to accept connections on a given port, there must be a piece of software listening for a connection on that port, otherwise no connection can be made.

Comment: but can't only one application use a port at any given time?

Comment: That only applies on the server side (the side listening for incoming connection requests). That is, a server cannot have more than 1 service listening for TCP connections on a given port. That's why different services (web server, file server, FTP server, etc.) can all be running on the same machine - they each have their own port they they use to listen for connections.

Comment: @normalocity re privileged ports, I think it's often the other way around for incoming traffic, some providers like Telenet (Belgium) completely block the entire privileged port range for incoming traffic and allow customers to selectively open nonprivileged ports.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to look at a couple of alternative solutions that are less cumbersome - scanning for open ports can take quite some time, can cause panicky reactions from firewalls that feel attacked, and so on.  There are a couple of techniques that are in active use and have been developed exactly to solve the problem of servers behind firewalls.

1. [UDP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching), zero user side configuration needed.  Simple explanation on how Skype uses this technique can be found [here](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html)
2. [UPnP / IGD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol) could be used as an alternative, though less devices support it out of the box nowadays due to security problems.
3. [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) with a Java implementation of client and serverside called [JSTUN](http://jstun.javawi.de/)

Whatever solution you choose, test it thoroughly with different internet service providers, there's a plethora of limitations you can expect wrt blocked ports.